# Is there a better way to combine these two Linq expressions?

Tags: c#, linq

I have two LINQ expressions that I think I should be able to combine into one.

I have a list of referrers, each of which references multiple items, and I'm trying to determine the most popular items.  Each referrer conveys a unique vote score to a referenced item.  That is, referrer 1 might give a vote of 0.2, and referrer 2 might give a vote of 0.03.

A simplified `Referrer` class:

```
class Referrer
{
    public double VoteScore { get; private set; }
    public List<int> Items { get; private set; }
    public Referrer(double v)
    {
        VoteScore = v;
        Items = new List<int>();
    }
}
```

My two Linq expressions are:

```
var Votes =
    from r in Referrers
    from v in r.Items
    select new { ItemNo = v, Vote = r.VoteScore };
```

That gives me a list:

```
ItemNo:1, Vote:0.2
ItemNo:3, Vote:0.2
ItemNo:1, Vote:0.03
```

Now, I can group, sum, and sort with my second expression:

```
var SortedByScore = 
    from v in Votes
    group v by v.ItemNo into g
    let score = g.Sum((v) => v.Vote)
    orderby score descending
    select new { ItemNo = g.Key, Score = score };
```

Is it possible to combine these into a single expression?  I realize that I can chain the expressions, that is:

```
var SortedByScore = 
    from v in
        (from r in ActivatedReferrers
         from v in r.Items
         select new { ItemNo = v, Vote = r.VoteScore })
    group v by v.ItemNo into g
    let score = g.Sum((v) => v.Vote)
    orderby score descending
    select new { ItemNo = g.Key, Score = score };
```

But that's not really any different from what I already have--it's just nesting the first expression inside the second.  Is there another way that combines the two expressions into one?

Comment: Seems like a strange model to me. A "referrer" gives the same vote score to each item in its list of items? I'd love to know what you're modelling.

Comment: Think of how PageRank works. That's not what I'm building, but the idea is similar.  Basically, each referrer gets a score of 1.0, and that score is spread out evenly across all the things its list. The model is simple, but effective for what I'm doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
from r in Referrers
from v in r.Items
group r.VoteScore by v into g
let score = g.Sum()
orderby score descending
select new { ItemNo = g.Key, Score = score }
```

Comment: That appears to be what I was looking for. Thank you. Now I'm going to go study the grouping syntax. This is so simple that my missing it means that I don't fully understand grouping.

Comment: Ah, just realized what I ended up with is exactly what you have.  I was focused more on simplifying what Jim had and didn't notice that `Items` was actually `List<int>` which changed things due to the nested query and reuse of the `v` variable.